# How do I write an Android.bp for kernel modules?

Tags: android, kernel-module, android-soong

I want to use

```
cc_prebuilt_library_shared {
    name: "wlan",
    relative_install_path: "modules",
    target: {
        android_arm: {
            srcs: "lib/wlan.ko"
        }
    },
    vendor: true
}
```

My concern is that when it's installed it will be rename to lib/modules/wlan.so

Is there a way to ensure when installed it will be lib/modules/wlan.ko